# UserProfileMgtService is not able to find user in WSO2 IS 5.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently updated my environment from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to WSO2 IS 5.2.0. My environment consists of 2 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines). I am also using the so called WSO2 IS Admin services.

As mentioned in the heading I am consuming the UserProfileMgtService
(https://url:port/services/UserProfileMgtService?wsdl).
In combination with it I am using OAuth2TokenValidationService
(https://url:port/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService?wsdl).

If I pass valid access token to the OAuth2TokenValidationService I am able to fill in with data OAuth2TokenValidationResponseDTO object by using the Validate method of the OAuth2TokenValidationService. As result I am able to extract the authorizedUser and pass it to the getUserProfile method of the UserProfileMgtService. I am using the standard carbon.super domain and I am using the email as username. For example I am passing the following two parameters to the getUserProfile:
"admin@admin.com@carbon.super" as username
"default" as profileName
And as result I receive the following message:
**UserNotFound: User admin@admin.com@carbon.superdoes not exist in: PRIMARY**
If I remove the "@carbon.super" from the authorizedUser, everything is fine and I am able to get the user profile information. This is quite important for me since I am using multitenancy of the IS and there is a case that I might have the following users:
admin@admin.com@test.net
admin@admin.com@test2.net

I noticed that this service was not working this way in WSO2 IS 5.0.0. I started experiencing this issue after the upgrade.

Is this a desired behavior and is introduced because of the change in the API in IS 5.2.0? If so is there another way to be able to get the user profile using the "username"+"tenant-domain"(that is retrieved by the OAuth2TokenValidationService as authorized user when passing valid access token).
Is it possible that this is caused because of misconfiguration? If so which is the file that needs to updated and what exactly should be modified in it?
Is there a place where more information could be retrieved for the WSO2 IS 5.2.0 Admin Services?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserProfileMgtService in Identity Server is an Admin Service. In WSO2 Admin Services, the tenant domain is identified by authenticated user and it should not pass with username.

**username should be tenant free username.**

So, you can remove carbon.super portion from the username and then it will work.

In tenant setup, you need to authenticate with a tenant user (Ex admin@admin.com@test.net) in order to access these API. So, like in the super tenant, you can use tenant free username and then it will work.

For example, if you want to get user profile of user : testuser@admin.com in tenant domain test.net, your request should be like bellow image.

[image]

Thanks
Isura.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got your point (I think), I am using the admin credentials to give context of the service and then I am only the username. If I pass admin credentials of the carbon.super, I am going to be retrieving profiles from the carbon.super tenant. And if I pass admin credentials of the test.net tenant I will be retrieving identities from the test.net tenant.

Comment: Yes. You are right. In order to retrieve profile in a given tenant, it is required to authenticate with the same tenant.